# Removal warning "Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")" will affect functionality?

Tags: android, eclipse, warnings, suppress-warnings

Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked"). I am getting these warnings.If i remove this ,**will it affect the project or any functionality**.I am not getting the exact use of this.Can anyone help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.Removing the Suppress Warnings will not affect any part  of your code ....

**Suppress Warnings**
Indicates that the named compiler warnings should be suppressed in the annotated element (and in all program elements contained in the annotated element). Note that the set of warnings suppressed in a given element is a superset of the warnings suppressed in all containing elements. For example, if you annotate a class to suppress one warning and annotate a method to suppress another, both warnings will be suppressed in the method.

As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is effective. If you want to suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that method rather than its class.

Comment: that means this suppress warning is used only removing warnings in eclipse??or any other use by adding this in the code?

Comment: ok. so when we change the target version/min version ,these warnings appear and to remove it only we are using this suppress warnings? And for functionality of those code in higher versions we need to do something separately?rt?